# Spring Tool Suite (STS) 3.7.3 RELEASE Updating Software

Tags: spring-tool-suite

When I am doing Help --> Check for Updates ... I am getting an error below. Tried clearing p2 cache directory and restarting IDE many times but it did not help. Tried disabling the SpringSource update site as well but it did not help either. I am also attaching the snapshot of the update sites below. Please help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMTrE.png)

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session
>   context was:(profile=DefaultProfile,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
>   action=). No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,javaewah,0.7.9.v201605172130 No repository found
>   containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cft.server.branding.core,1.0.0.v201603222052
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cft.server.branding.ui,1.0.0.v201603222052 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cft.server.core,1.0.101.v201603222052 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cft.server.rse,1.0.0.v201603222052 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cft.server.standalone.core,1.0.0.v201603222052
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cft.server.standalone.ui,1.0.0.v201603222052
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cft.server.ui,1.0.100.v201603222052 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cft.server.verify.ui,1.0.0.v201603222052 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit,4.4.0.201606070830-r No repository found
>   containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.core,4.4.0.201606070830-r No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.doc,4.4.0.201606070830-r No repository
>   found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.ui,4.4.0.201606070830-r No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.ui,4.4.0.201606070830-r No repository
>   found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jgit,4.4.0.201606070830-r No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jgit.archive,4.4.0.201606070830-r No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.archetype.common,1.6.3.20160209-1444 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.core,1.6.3.20160209-1446 No repository
>   found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui,1.6.3.20160209-1446 No repository
>   found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.discovery,1.6.3.20160209-1446 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.editor,1.6.3.20160209-1446 No repository
>   found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.editor.xml,1.6.3.20160209-1446 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.jdt,1.6.3.20160209-1446 No repository
>   found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.ui,1.6.3.20160209-1446 No repository
>   found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.launching,1.6.3.20160209-1446 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.lifecyclemapping.defaults,1.6.3.20160209-1446
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.maven.indexer,1.6.3.20160209-1444 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime,1.6.3.20160209-1444 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple,1.6.3.20160209-1444
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.model.edit,1.6.3.20160209-1446 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.profiles.core,1.6.3.20160209-1446 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.profiles.ui,1.6.3.20160209-1446 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.refactoring,1.6.3.20160209-1446 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.scm,1.6.3.20160209-1446 No repository
>   found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.core,3.20.1.v20160614-0000 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.ide,3.20.1.v20160613-2359 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.ui,3.20.1.v20160614-0000 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.core,3.20.1.v20160613-2359 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.identity.core,1.12.1.v20160613-2359
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.net,3.20.1.v20160613-2359 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.core,1.12.1.v20160613-2359
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.feed,1.12.1.v20160613-2359
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.ui,1.12.1.v20160613-2359
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.repositories.core,1.12.1.v20160613-2359
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.repositories.ui,1.12.1.v20160613-2359
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.screenshots,3.20.1.v20160613-2359
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui,3.20.1.v20160613-2359 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.workbench,3.20.1.v20160613-2359
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc,3.20.1.v20160613-2359 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.context.core,3.20.1.v20160613-2359 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.context.tasks.ui,3.20.1.v20160613-2359
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.context.ui,3.20.1.v20160613-2359 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.debug.ui,3.20.1.v20160613-2359 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.discovery.core,3.20.1.v20160613-2359 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.discovery.ui,3.20.1.v20160613-2359 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.help.ui,3.20.1.v20160614-0000 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.ide.ant,3.20.1.v20160613-2359 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.ide.ui,3.20.1.v20160613-2359 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.java.tasks,3.20.1.v20160613-2359 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.java.ui,3.20.1.v20160613-2359 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.monitor.core,3.20.1.v20160613-2359 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.monitor.ui,3.20.1.v20160613-2359 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.resources.ui,3.20.1.v20160613-2359 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.bugs,3.20.1.v20160614-0000 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.core,3.20.1.v20160614-0000 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.index.core,3.20.1.v20160614-0000
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.index.ui,3.20.1.v20160614-0000 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.search,3.20.1.v20160614-0000 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui,3.20.1.v20160614-0000 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.team.ui,3.20.1.v20160613-2359 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.sonatype.m2e.buildhelper,0.15.0.201212120353 No
>   repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.cft.server.core.feature,1.0.1.v201603222052
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.cft.server.ui.feature,1.0.0.v201603222052
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.egit,4.4.0.201606070830-r No
>   repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.egit.mylyn,4.4.0.201606070830-r
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jgit,4.4.0.201606070830-r No
>   repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.m2e.feature,1.6.3.20160209-1446
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla_feature,3.20.1.v20160614-0000
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons,3.20.1.v20160613-2359
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.identity,1.12.1.v20160613-2359
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications,1.12.1.v20160613-2359
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.repositories,1.12.1.v20160613-2359
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.context_feature,3.20.1.v20160613-2359
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.discovery,3.20.1.v20160613-2359
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.ide_feature,3.20.1.v20160613-2359
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.java_feature,3.20.1.v20160613-2359
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.monitor,3.20.1.v20160613-2359
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ide,3.20.1.v20160614-0000
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.team_feature,3.20.1.v20160613-2359
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn_feature,3.20.1.v20160614-0000
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.sonatype.m2e.buildhelper.feature,0.15.0.201212120353

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RjqT.png)

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do exactly, but in case the cached p2 data is the problem, I would export all the update sites from those preferences, delete them in Eclipse/STS, restart Eclipse/STS, and import them back. Maybe that helps.

Comment: In addition to that the list of update sites looks rather long to me. Maybe some cleanup work is required here, too, to avoid conflicting updates in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The issue mostly has to do with stale cached data (I experienced the same). The following should solve your problem.

1. Go to: 'Preferences > Available Software Sites'
2. Mark all, and 'Export' to file.
3. Delete everything (all the links)
4. Close and Start STS
5. Go to: 'Preferences > Available Software Sites'
6. 'Import' from the previously saved file.
7. Go to, 'Help > Check for updates'
8. Update

Basically this procedure clears up all the stale data.